# Integration of $d(\cos\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Now, I've obviously come across the following during my physics degree:

$$
\int{\cos\theta\,d\theta}
$$

But I'm starting to see this being introduced to this:

$$
\int{d(\cos\theta)}
$$

Could anyone just give a foolproof dummies guide to this second expression. For me, it has to equal $\cos\theta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is equal to $\cos(\theta)$. This can be thought of as a $u$-substitution with $d(f(x)):=f'(x)dx$. This notation plays very nicely with the $\frac{df}{dx}$ notation for derivatives, giving you the ability to simplify statements that come up a lot in physics, like $\int f(x(t))v(t)dt=\int f(x(t))\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\int f(x)dx$

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as $u$ substitution (or the chain rule), where your $u=\cos(\theta)$ so that $$du=d(\cos(\theta))=-\sin(\theta) d\theta$$
Edit: And of course by the fundamental theorem of calculus, integrating $d(\cos(\theta)$ this is just $\cos(\theta)$.